# Adding C++ support to external toolchain in buildroot

Tags: cross-compiling, toolchain, buildroot, gnu-toolchain

I'm using buildroot version 2011.11 for cross compiling my application. I'm trying to add oprofile to my application, and oprofile depends on c++ support. But when I checked using make menuconfig, under toolchain, our Toolchain type is selected as External toolchain. Toolchain is  CodeSourcery M68K uClinux 4.4.53, and the box to download the toolchain automatically is selected for us.

When I change it to Crosstool-NG toolchain, I was getting the option "Enable C++ support (NEW)" but for us (External toolchain), this option is not available.

Kindly help me in adding c++ support to my build environment

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the case of external toolchains, the option is called "Toolchain has C++ support?".

Please updated your Buildroot version to a more recent version. Also, if you are using Buildroot to target m68k platforms, do not hesitate to send patches, we know the Buildroot support for this architecture is far from perfect.